# How to i iterate and compare two lists

Tags: java, list

```java
List 1 = [a, b, c, d, 1, e, 1, , 2]
List 2 = [a, b, f, d, 1, e, 1, g, 2]
o/p list = [, , f, , , , , g, ]
```

Here I'm trying to compare two lists position wise that is the first element from list1 has to be compared with only the first element of list2 and if they are equal it should be replaced with the empty string in the output list and if they are different the element in the second list has to be updated in the output.

Comment: find the diff between A and B,  then iterate over that result and replaces what is not in with empty space

Comment: Please include the code you have tried. Right now your question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what went wrong? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the input lists should have the same length, therefore it is possible to iterate both lists using index, compare the elements at the same index, and put the necessary into the result.

1. Using `for` loop

```java
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0, n = list1.size(); i < n; i++) {
    result.add(Objects.equals(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)) ? "" : list2.get(i));
}
```

2. Using Stream API (`IntStream`)

```java
List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Objects.equals(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)) ? "" : list2.get(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```